# network admin pages not linked to correctly

Tags: multisite, wp-admin, network-admin

I've just converted my local development install of wordpress to a network, and everything seems to work, except the parts of the admin panel relating to network management don't have the correct links (I have the core wordpress files in a "wordpress/" subdirectory.) The network related parts get links generated without the "wordpress/" component, but everything else continues to work correctly.

Is there a step I missed to get my "network" to play nice with this directory setup?

Comment: I am pretty sure network sites cannot be installed in a sub-directory, I would start by moving the files to root to see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: unfortunately you're correct

Comment: if you mean like the wp-skeleton setup for multisite, then maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594106/wordpress-skeleton-vvv-multisite-and-the-right-nginx-rules/34659119#34659119) can help?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress does not support serving a network with the core code in a subdirectory. My site works now that I moved everything back into the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the WP Codex it should work.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

> As of Version 3.5, Multisite users may use all of the functionality listed below. If you are running a version of WordPress older than 3.5, please update before installing a Multisite WordPress install on a subdirectory.